# Is the importance_type 'split' of lightgbm the same as the importance_type 'weight` in xgboost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm

Is the importance_type 'split' of lightgbm the same as the importance_type 'weight' in xgboost?

In other words, are the following the same?

```
booster.feature_importance(importance_type = 'split') # for lightgbm
```

and

```
get_fscore(importance_type='weight') # for xgboost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the slightly different wording, they are the same indeed.

From the LightGBM [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.feature_importance):

> If "split", result contains numbers of times the feature is used in a model.

From the XGBoost [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html?highlight=get_score#xgboost.Booster.get_score):

> 'weight’: the number of times a feature is used to split the data across all trees.

No coincidence that these importance types are the default choices in the two packages respectively.